# ajax search result not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

[Dealer name search result issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CPRJ.jpg)
I am trying to use autocomplete ajax search, and although I am getting response it is not displaying properly.

I have checked the network response and i can find the search results.

The number of rows are also creating properly, just that it doesn't show the values. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#OrderName").keyup(function(){
        var name = $('#OrderName').val();
         $("#OrderName").autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'search_user')); ?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {q: request.term},
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
        });
    });
});
```

/* The following css I'm trying is also not working. */

```
ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{width:initial; font-size: 20px; color:black; }

ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu li:first-child a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: what is `response(data);`? did you have this function `response()`?

Comment: I was trying to use response to populate the suggestions. The following shows me the result console.log(data[0].User.name);. basically need to display the objects as suggestions.

Comment: example  searching and filtering. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/